# Activerecord iteration / append an exception at a certain position

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, iteration

I'm looking for a way to include a specific element at a certain position inside an iteration

Not experienced enough to use the right pattern (hence to search here on stack overflow with the right keywords, afraid of getting some duplicate question with this one)… but the base idea would as the following :

```
<% Post.all.each do |post| %>
    <% if Post.all.index(post) == 5 # or any position %>
        # render some html element (some kind of exception)
    <% else %>
        <%= post.title %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

But just without skipping any records in my post array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I have totally understood your request. [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) may help you, and if you don't use the `else`, you won't skip any records :

```
<% Post.all.each_with_index do |post, index| %>
  <% if index == 5 # or any position %>
    # render some html element (some kind of exception)
  <% end %>
  <%= post.title %>      
<% end %>
```